# Spring Batch | Does JdbcPagingItemReader<T> supports multiple DataSource to support join query across multiple datasource?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I do have SQL query reader for ItemReader with only single .

But my query exception is to join tables from two different datasource and provide single output result.. something like below

```
  <bean id="userFinder"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader"
        scope="step">
    ...
    ...
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource1" ref="dataSource1" />
            <property name="dataSource2" ref="dataSource2" />
            <property name="selectClause"
                value="SELECT ALIAS1.COL1, ALIAS2.COL2 " />
            <property name="fromClause" value="FROM dataSource1.TABLE1.ALIAS1, dataSource2.TABLE 2.ALIAS2" />
            </property>
            <property name="sortKey" value="WLT_ID" />
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Comment: `DataSource` meaning an actual `java.sql.DataSource`?  If that is it, no.  I'm unaware of any technology that supports joining across databases via straight SQL like that...

Comment: yes. In my application, I do have two datasource available as a JNDI look up. In oracle backend, those are defined as a separate USER/schema.
I want to join table1 from first datasource/schema with table2 from second datasource/schema. In plain SQL, we can join tables from two different schema/users, I am looking that support in ***this reader. Is that possible?

Comment: Alternnatives would be to use a database link (ORACLE), the FEDERATED MySQL Storage Engine (MySQL), a Dblink (PostgreSQL), etc.

Answer (score 1):

in single query you will be not able to join two different database.  I think in java you will not able to use two datasource to run one query.

You can write your custom ItemReader  and inject both datasource.
retrieve data from both table and do join in java code. but this will be very expensive operation

Comment: Yes... wanted to avoid custom implementation.